# Ray for numpy multiprocesing

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, ray

I am trying to use Ray for multiprocessing on CPU and GPU
Unfortunately, i cannot share the whole dataframe but here is a replica of my dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

issues_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['issue_id','step','conversion_rate'],data=[['01-abc-234',0,0.45],['01-abc-234',1,0.35],['01-abc-234',2,0.15],['01-abc-234',3,1],['02-abc-234',0,0.05],['02-abc-234',1,0.15],['02-abc-234',2,0.65],['02-abc-234',3,1]])
```

This is my ray initialization

```
import ray

ray.init(num_cpus=8,num_gpus=1,ignore_reinit_error=True)
```

this is how i am using ray

```
%%time
@ray.remote
def calculate_conversion_step(issues_df):
    cond0, cond1, cond2 = issues_df['step'].eq(0), issues_df['step'].eq(1), issues_df['step'].eq(2)
    s1 = issues_df.groupby('issue_id')['domain_step_conversion'].transform(lambda x: x.where(cond1 | cond2).prod())
    s2 = issues_df.groupby('issue_id')['domain_step_conversion'].transform(lambda x: x.where(cond2).sum())
    issues_df['conversion_step'] = np.select([cond0, cond1], [s1, s2], 1)
    return issues_df


# Use the function
issues_df_id = ray.put(issues_df)  # Put the DataFrame into the Ray object store
new_issues_df_id = calculate_conversion_step.remote(issues_df_id)  # Call the function
new_issues_df = ray.get(new_issues_df_id)
```

I am wondering if there is anything i can do to make this even faster? Any help is appreciated

Comment: More context and details are required. What part is slow? Is it the function itself, even if it resides outside `Ray`, or it behaves like this only if it becomes `remote`? Also, please provide us with some performance metrics, as we don't have your dataset.